# viper changing data type on set

Tags: go, viper-go

I have folder with json files like:

- schema
  file1.json
  file2.json

and I am trying to iterate and get all data from each file in `map[string]interface{}`

and I am getting data in such type successfully. but when I store it to the viper config it changed to `map[json:map[]]`

here is the snip

```
func iterateFiles(f string) {

    pwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    path := pwd + "/schema/"

    if f != path {

        file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(f)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error reading file: " + f)
        }

        var result map[string]interface{}
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &result)

        _, filename := filepath.Split(f)

        fmt.Println(result)

        viper.Set(filename, result)
    }
}
```

fmt.Println(result) returns me:

```
map[callback_url:[required url] next_date:[required]]
map[ref:[required string]]
map[ref:[required string]]
```

but when I try to get the map from viper I receive:

```
result := viper.GetStringMap(action)

fmt.Println(result)

map[json:map[callback_url:[required url] next_date:[required]]]
```

Could someone point me in the right direction so I can receive the type which I stored?

Answer (score 0):

resolved it like this

```
r := viper.GetStringMap(action)
result := r["json"].(map[string]interface{})
```

if you know more efficient way please let me know